# Tarski Monster group with prime 5

Tags: gr.group-theory, open-problems

Does the Tarski Monster group with prime 5 exist? I know that for 2 and 3, the group does not exist, but what about 5?

Comment: The Burnside problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_problem for exponent 5 still seems to be open.

Comment: It is an open problem. It is not even known whether finitely generated groups of exponent 5 are finite.

Comment: Then in that case, i will try it.

Comment: @Deibor: Good choice! Finding a Tarski monster for $p=5$ is the surest way to get a Fields medal.

Comment: It not excluded neither that $B(2,5)$ is infinite but there's no Tarski monster of exponent 5. If one shows there is no such Tarski monster I'm not sure it would imply Fields medal :)

Comment: (For completeness: I think that by Tarski monster of prime exponent $p$ it is meant an infinite group in which every nontrivial proper subgroup is cyclic of order $p$. Such a group is necessarily non-abelian and 2-generated, namely by any pair of non-commuting elements).

Comment: Of course, you won't get a Fields medal even with a Tarski monster, if you are at least 40 years old on January 1st of the next year that is congruent to 2 mod 4.